# Skip over strings that are not found Python

Tags: python, string, loops, skip

There is more to this script but I cut out the portion I am currently working on. This is part of a `for` loop, there're a lot of excel files to loop through.

`counts4=stops3[stops3['Name']==(String2)]` is where I'm having some problems. I get an error stating that `"index is out of bounds"` because it can't find the string. I have some strings that might not be inside `stops3` so, is there a way to skip over the string if it's not found and continue on to the next string? The strings change as the loop goes through each excel file, I have 100's of files.

```
stops2 = pd.read_excel(Hold,usecols = "B,D", skiprows=3,header=None,index=False)
stops2.columns=['Hold','Name']
stops3=stops2[stops2.Hold != 'Pace']
String2=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
counts4=stops3[stops3['Name']==(String2)]
counts5=counts4['Name'].value_counts()
z3=counts5[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple *if* condition to only execute the following code if String2 has a value.

```
if len(String2) > 0:
    counts4=stops3[stops3['Name']==(String2)]
    counts5=counts4['Name'].value_counts()
    z3=counts5[0]
```

It would be great if you could include some more details about your excel file. It would then be easier for someone to answer your question.